# i18n localizing a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rubygems

I need to localize a gem. The gem does process text. While processing the text it is listening for different words like **Friday** or **Next Week**. Now I want to listen it for translations too, like **Freitag** and **Nächste Woche**.

Do I just need to create the yaml files and use the t method in the ruby classes? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you guys!

Comment: This is a bit vague, can you explain specifically what you're trying to achieve with some code samples?